# Cant get reference to an image using SDWebImage framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, sdwebimage

i have a table that parse through an XML and get values for images loaded by URL links. There is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UILabel *labelText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    labelText.text = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashie.png" ]completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){


    }];

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

return cell;
}
```

Yes, it works, but now i need to modify my UIImage (with category, for making it right size), and i simply can't get reference to it. When i tried to modify an image in completion block like this :

```
 [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashie.png" ]completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){

        [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];

    }];
```

There is absolutely no effect, even when i change image for nil, its actually did nothing, so my question is: how to get instance variable of UIImage in method:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"imageFirst"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dashie.png" ]completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){


    }];
```

and modify it? Or how could i pass instance variable of UIImage for this method that i created before? That question may sound silly, but i need advice.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: log error , if you are getting any.

Comment: What if you try using `cell.imageView` instead of `image`, inside the `setImageWithURL` block

Comment: I don't have errors, i just got inappropriate image on cells (incorrect size). Merlevede, I'm not understand what u mean, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no error is returned to the completion block, `[image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];` will create a new image for you, but you still need to do something with it:

```
UIImage *resizedImage = [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

You do need to be careful though, the cell may have been reused before the image is ready, so using `cell` in the block could be wrong. Better:

```
UIImage *resizedImage = [image resizedImageWithBounds:CGSizeMake(66, 66)];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = resizedImage;
```

Comment: Why you create resizedImage when u use image in cell.imageView.image?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage have image downloader, you can download image, change everything you need and set to imageView